# How to parse xml into json with jackson

Tags: java, xml, spring, parsing, jackson

Can someone point me to the correct way to convert xml into json with **jackson**?

I have one service that accepts a post request with an xml body, I want to take that xml and send it to another service as a json.

I've seen some examples where people use an `ObjectMapper`, but ideally, I would have an interface `ModelJsonView` and then use the `setMixInAnnotation()` method to bind it to the corresponding model class.

Comment: XML to JSON is a *conversion*, not a *deserialization*.

Comment: @Andreas edited thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
String xml = "<testName>Tester</testName><testValue>100</testValue>"
JSONObject xmlToJsonObject = XML.toJSONObject(xml);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
Object json = mapper.readValue(xmlToJsonObject.toString(), Object.class);
System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(json));
```

Include org.json and jackson jars.